# Dirac delta function of centre of mass frame

Tags: quantum-field-theory, antimatter, dirac-delta-distributions

In Peskin chapter 5.3, it is discussing about vector meson production in center of mass frame, PS rewrite delta function $\delta(P^o-K^o)=2K^o\delta(P^2-K^2)$ where $(P^o,\vec{p})$ correspond to a pair of electron and positron, $(K_o,\vec{k})$ correspond to a vector meson produced.

When I tried to work it out, in centre of mass frame, $\vec{p}=\vec{k}=0$

I get $P^2=(P^o)^2,K^2=(K^o)^2$,

$\delta(P^2-K^2)=\delta((P^o)^2-(K^o)^2)=\frac{\delta(P^o-K^o)}{|2K^o|}+\frac{\delta(P^o+K^o)}{|2K^o|}$

I do not know why second term is vanished, is it due to time order?

Comment: No, it's zero cause delta function property which is zero when $x \neq 0$. In your case you have $P_0, K_0 \geq 0$ so the sum is always different from zero.

Comment: Thanks, that means we work with positive energies only.